# Blender Scale Issues with MakeHuman and Mixamo Fuse

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have imported the Mixamo Fuse default female character and a MakeHuman MHX2 file. I want to project the UV map of the Fuse default onto the MakeHuman character because Mixamo Fuse has a strict and different UV map in order to import to Fuse. (Is that possible, someone said to use the Shrinkwrap Modifier?)

See Here: https://community.mixamo.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205090387-UV-Map-Frustration-from-a-disabled-designer

I have a major scale issue (yes, I did change the MakeHuman model to meters before exporting) It does not matter which model I import first or second. The first model imports to the correct scale. The second model imports as a tiny and I mean almost not visible from any angle or zoom  factor model.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a ~.blend file containing both imported images, this is a bit of shot in the dark, but the first thing I would try is to open the file, select the model that is in the smaller scale in object mode, then switch to edit mode, and scale the model up until the proportions approximate those of the first model imported. Then switch back to object mode, and apply the scale of the object using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>A</kbd>.

Of course you could use the same technique in the reverse direction to scale the larger object down to the smaller one.

Comment: I will try to save the issue as a bled file so you can see, but I will try what you said first. Thanks for your help. Do you have any insight as to if Shrink-wrapping the UV maps from Mixamo Fuse to my MakeHuman character will work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. The shrinkwrap modifier does not figure into my workflow very often.